# Spring Security Kerberos/SPNEGO Extension Error "Access is denied"

Tags: java, spring-security, spnego

I am getting trouble with Spring Security Kerberos/SPNEGO Extension example.
I am using:

- windows 2008
- Tomcat 7
- Spring Security Kerberos/SPNEGO Extension
- 1.7 jdk1.7.0_09

I was using this blog for setting example:
http://blog.springsource.com/2009/09/28/spring-security-kerberos/
So I begin:
In windows 2008 server I created principal using command:

```
C:\>ktpass -princ HTTP/XENA2.mydomain.org@MYDOMAIN.ORG -pass xena2 -mapuser MYDOMAIN\xena2 -out c:\xena2.keytab -kvno 0 -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -mapop set -crypto All
```

and got this result:

```
Targeting domain controller: SERVAS.mydomain.org
Using legacy password setting method
Successfully mapped HTTP/XENA2.mydomain.org to xena2.
Key created.
Key created.
Key created.
Key created.
Key created.
Output keytab to c:\xena2.keytab:
Keytab version: 0x502
keysize 59 HTTP/XENA2.mydomain.org@MYDOMAIN.ORG ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 0 etype 0x1 (DES-CBC-CRC) keylength 8 (0xa8fbb6cde346579e)
keysize 59 HTTP/XENA2.mydomain.org@MYDOMAIN.ORG ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 0 etype 0x3 (DES-CBC-MD5) keylength 8 (0xa8fbb6cde346579e)
keysize 67 HTTP/XENA2.mydomain.org@MYDOMAIN.ORG ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 0 etype 0x17 (RC4-HMAC) keylength 16 (0x9200ac342847bbeb60bdc8a5821a5fac)
keysize 83 HTTP/XENA2.mydomain.org@MYDOMAIN.ORG ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 0 etype 0x12 (AES256-SHA1) keylength 32 (0x904dbaf53675f18254aaacdcef91cd29f5bb0a3d10919b983c76b9f00014d966)
keysize 67 HTTP/XENA2.mydomain.org@MYDOMAIN.ORG ptype 1 (KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL) vno 0 etype 0x11 (AES128-SHA1) keylength 16 (0x56fd36768f184efeb729eb8b22c4c168)
```

After that I copied xena2.keytab file to computer (XENA2) and tested connection to server:

```
C:\>kinit HTTP/XENA2.mydomain.org@MYDOMAIN.ORG -k -t xena2.keytab
New ticket is stored in cache file C:\Users\xena2\krb5cc_xena2
```

Looks good for me until now.

Added variables to Tomcat startup:

```
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=C:\krb5.conf
-Djava.security.krb5.realm=MYDOMAIN.ORG
-Djava.security.krb5.kdc=servas.MYDOMAIN.ORG
```

Created file **krb5.conf** in C: disk:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = MYDOMAIN.ORG
    default_tkt_enctypes = aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
    default_tgs_enctypes = aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
    permitted_enctypes   = aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc

[realms]
    MYDOMAIN.ORG  = {
        kdc = servas.mydomain.org 
        default_domain = MYDOMAIN.ORG
}

[domain_realm]
    .MYDOMAIN.ORG = MYDOMAIN.ORG
```

Updated **spnego.xml** file like this:

```
<property name="servicePrincipal" value="HTTP/XENA2.mydomain.org@MYDOMAIN.ORG" />
<property name="keyTabLocation" value="classpath:xena2.keytab" />
```

Also tried:

```
<property name="keyTabLocation" value="FILE:C:/xena2.keytab" />
```

Deployed project to tomcat ran it (in different computer than server), went to restricted place, wrote user and pass and got HTTP 500 error.
Log file looks like this (a bit cleaned):

```
2012-10-26 15:48:25 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started 
Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Oct 26 15:48:28 EEST 2012]; root of context hierarchy 
Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spnego.xml] 
Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl] 
Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas] 
Loaded schema mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.2.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.2.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd} 
Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd 
Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.0.xsd 
Loading bean definitions 
Loaded NamespaceHandler mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/p=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee=org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop=org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/security=org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx=org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task=org.springframework.scheduling.config.TaskNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang=org.springframework.scripting.config.LangNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context=org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler} 
Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 300, <spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter>, order = 1200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1800, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 1900] 
Neither XML 'id' nor 'name' specified - using generated bean name [org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator#1a40cf5] 
Neither XML 'id' nor 'name' specified - using generated bean name [org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig#0] 
Loaded 18 bean definitions from location pattern [/WEB-INF/spnego.xml] 

...

Eagerly caching bean 'kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider' to allow for resolving potential circular references 
Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator#1a40cf5' 
Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator#1a40cf5' 
Your keytab is in the classpath. This file needs special protection and shouldn't be in the classpath. JAAS may also not be able to load this file from classpath. 
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator false KeyTab is file:/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/webapps/spring-security-kerberos-sample-1.0.0.M2/WEB-INF/classes/xena2.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/XENA2.mydomain.org@MYDOMAIN.ORG tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
principal is HTTP/XENA2.mydomain.org@MYDOMAIN.ORG
Will use keytab
Ordering keys wrt default_tkt_enctypes list
Config name: classpath:krb5.conf
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 17 16 23 1 3.
Commit Succeeded 

Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator#1a40cf5' 
Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dummyUserDetailsService' 
Creating instance of bean 'dummyUserDetailsService' 
Eagerly caching bean 'dummyUserDetailsService' to allow for resolving potential circular references 
Finished creating instance of bean 'dummyUserDetailsService' 

...

HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT 
No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@12ef3bb. A new one will be created. 
/secure/index.jsp at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter@2b7684' 
/secure/index.jsp at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@171ff47' 
/secure/index.jsp at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@12ec880' 
/secure/index.jsp at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2a3db5' 
Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faeba70: Principal: anonymousUser; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffbcba8: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.189.1; SessionId: 3FBB484FF373A965218474C88211DFA7; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS' 
/secure/index.jsp at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@139406a' 
/secure/index.jsp at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1b42103' 
/secure/index.jsp at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@e38854' 
Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/secure/index.jsp'; to: '/secure/index.jsp' 
Candidate is: '/secure/index.jsp'; pattern is /secure/**; matched=true 
Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /secure/index.jsp; Attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY] 
Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faeba70: Principal: anonymousUser; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffbcba8: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.189.1; SessionId: 3FBB484FF373A965218474C88211DFA7; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS 
Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@183b617, returned: 0 
Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@27cff7, returned: -1 
Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point 
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.web.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:152)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

So question is Why I am getting this error: *org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied*

Could it be that keytab file wasn't used successfully? If yes so Why?
Also I think this error produced another error:
*Caused by: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)*

I hope this is enough information and someone will help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so no one never done this before?

Comment: Did you ever get any resolution on this issue?  I am experiencing the same thing after upgrading to Java 7.  Exactly the same version of Java 7 too.

Comment: I used WAFFLE after this :?

Comment: Hmm, thanks but I need it to work on linux too.  :/  My problem seems to be closer to this though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803458/kerberos-broken-after-upgrading-from-java6-to-java7

Answer (score 0):

Besides that this extension is crap, your client sends you a NTLM token instead of a Kerberos one. This behavior is absolutely correct because the client can negotiate (which it does here as fallback). Check your entire Kerberos, DNS, AD setup. Use Wireshark!

Comment: Michael-O...why do you say the extension sucks?  I'm getting ready to start an enhancement to a system where I need SSO of a Spring web app in a Windows environment, and I thought SPNEGO/Kerberos was the way to go...?

Comment: Kerberos is the way to go but that extension is implented halfheartedly. I haven't even filed issues because I do expect that they will be fixed anyway. I have written an extension my own which works now it is supposed to work with GSS-API. And yes, I will publish it as open source!

Comment: Michael-O: Did you ever publish your extension? I would love to have a look at it.

Comment: @jmh, as a [Tomcat module](http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/) yes but the Spring code not yet. I can share private code though until I will publish it. Contact me through sf.net.

Comment: I don't have time to switch from spring right now anyway, and I tried to sign up to sf.net, but they thought I was a spammer.  https://github.com/james-m-henderson if you want to let me know when the module is released proper.  Thanks!

Comment: @jmh, No need to drop Spring, drop me a mail: michael-o@users.sf.net.